# Problems with the width of the bitmap. The width is limited by the height of the screen

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-relativelayout

I'm creating a bitmap wich i need to use as background of a 320 width screen. The problem is that the bitmap is not getting the width i want. It is getting two empty spaces on the left and on the right. It is because it is fitting the height of the screen, but i dont want that, i want to force the bitmap to have the width i want. Doesn't matter if a portion of the height of the bitmap is out of the screen.

i need to force the width when i am adding the image to the layout, i mean that the image must be keep the aspect ratio, but the image must be higher than the height of the screen, and the image must be shown incomplete if the heigh of the image is higher than the height of the screen. Now this is not happening, because the layout is forcing the width to respect the image and show all the height of the image in the height of the screen, then i think the problem is on the layout rules

im creating the bitmap with:

```
View view;
Bitmap aux = Util.loadImage( filename ); //image loaded but with his original width
Bitmap image = Util.scaleBitmap(aux, 320); //scaling to 320
((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap( resource.image );

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 320 , h );
rlp.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
rlp.addRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP );

layout.addView( view , rlp );
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the rule with `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL`

Comment: i need the rule, i can't remove it, i need it because i'm using this code for a lot of sections of my app and they need to have the background images centered horizontally

Comment: i tryed deleting it and didn't works

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
((ImageView)view).setScaleType(ImageView.FitCenter);
```

To see more options see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: i tryed it, didn't works :/  this is the code that didn't works: ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap( resource.image );
    ((ImageView)view).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about the height you should use **CENTER_CROP**.

Define the scale type and then set the image.

> CENTER_CROP - Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).